# How to find the name change based on a specific TEXT and display its id and date using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a excel file containing three columns as shown below,

| id | name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 436 | Minster | 2020-04-15 |
| 436 | Minster (HTTP gg AG) | 2021-12-07 |
| 145 | Denskin (HTTP geplan) | 2020-07-24 |
| 145 | Denskinf HTTP DTAG | 2020-08-15 |
| 555 | Garben | 2021-03-05 |
| 555 | Wabern (HttP) | 2021-09-13 |
| 555 | Wabern Garben HTTP | 2022-04-18 |
| 737 | oyehausen | 2020-06-26 |
| 737 | WerrePark HTTP ag | 2020-07-14 |
| 737 | Werre Park (http ssd) | 2020-08-25 |
| 737 | Werre Park (HTTP) | 2021-03-15 |
| 884 | klintern | 2021-03-23 |
| 884 | kitern http | 2021-04-08 |
| 884 | Lausen (http los) | 2021-06-16 |
| 884 | kitener (http geplan) | 2021-07-24 |
| 584 | Lausern | 2020-08-15 |
| 584 | Lausern (HTTP DTAG gg) | 2021-03-05 |

Is it possible to filter out the id, name and the date when there is a change in name if **HTTP**  in any form like **HttP**, **(HTTP)**, **http** is included in the name at first event of occurance. For Example **id:436** doesn't have any form **http** text included in its first row but in the second row with the same **id:436** **HTTP** is included, but for the id:145 the first row itself has the HTTP. But I wanted to filter out the change in name which includes HTTP in any form of text either small or captial in the first event of occurence, with its id, name and date.

Expecting the result to be like,

| id | name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 436 | Minster (HTTP gg AG) | 2021-12-07 |
| 555 | Wabern (HttP) | 2021-09-13 |
| 737 | WerrePark HTTP ag | 2020-07-14 |
| 884 | kitern http | 2021-04-08 |
| 584 | Lausern (HTTP DTAG gg) | 2021-03-05 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a boolean mask `has_http` to identify the rows containing `http` then group this mask by `id` and use `shift` to create another boolean mask to identify whether previous row contains http. Then combine the masks using `&` to identify the changes

```
has_http = df['name'].str.contains(r'(?i)\bhttp\b')
mask = has_http & ~has_http.groupby(df['id']).shift(fill_value=True)
```

Now use the resulting mask to filter the rows

```
df[mask]


     id                    name        Date
1   436    Minster (HTTP gg AG)  2021-12-07
5   555           Wabern (HttP)  2021-09-13
8   737       WerrePark HTTP ag  2020-07-14
12  884             kitern http  2021-04-08
16  584  Lausern (HTTP DTAG gg)  2021-03-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using regex for any possible combination of uppercase/lowercase HTTP:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = [
["436", "Minster", "2020-04-15"],
["436", "Minster (HTTP gg AG)", "2021-12-07"],
["145", "Denskin (HTTP geplan)", "2020-07-24"],
["145", "Denskinf HTTP DTAG", "2020-08-15"],
["884", "klintern", "2021-03-23"],
["884", "klintern http", "2021-04-08"],
["884", "kitener (http geplan)", "2021-07-24"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'name', 'Date'])


filtered_df = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains("http", flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
filtered_df = filtered_df.groupby("id").first()
```

Output:

```
id                 name        Date
145  Denskin (HTTP geplan)  2020-07-24
436   Minster (HTTP gg AG)  2021-12-07
884          klintern http  2021-04-08
```

Comment: Kindly have a look at the expected result, id 145 should not be included in the output, the output should be considered, if the http is include only on or after the 2nd row or more. Not on the first row of the id.